# Is there a way to rotate getwave.io vectors for a react project

Tags: animation, rotation

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGVG.png)

I need help to write a code to match the figma design. Anytime I try the getwave.io vector doesn't position to the right and rotate

Comment: Please explain the desired output and the tech stack you are using in your project.

Comment: I am using react to creat the Navbar and I want to position the image behind the Navbar on right just as in the figma design.